# How to click into text box without ID or name? Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

Here is the html box I am trying to click onto,

```
<div style="min-height: 100px;" class="fr-element fr-view" dir="ltr" 
    aria-disabled="false" spellcheck="true"
    contenteditable="true">
    <p><br></p>
</div>
Then trying to reply with this button

<button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
    <span class="button-text">
        Post reply
    </span>
</button>
```

Here is what I have tried

```
WebElement Post;
Post = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'fr-element fr-view']"));
Post.click();
Post.sendKeys("okay");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button//span[text()='Post reply']")).click();
```

Comment: Your question heading is `click into text box` and with in the question body you mentioned about _trying to click onto_ and _Then trying to reply with this button_. Please [edit the question](/posts/54818669/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input element is a div and you were missing the closing round bracket on your contains expression.

The following should work:

```
Post = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'fr-element fr-view')]"));
```

You should test out the xpaths in the browser console as a sanity check. In Chrome just right click and click Inspect (ctrl + shift + i). Then go over to Elements tab and search (ctrl + f) on the elements using your xpath/css selector.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean by the second part sorry?

Comment: It's just a recommendation on how to test out your xpaths manually. You can just open chrome and go to the page you are using selenium on. Then when in the developer console you can test your xpaths directly in the search. If it works there it will work in selenium

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSSSelector** to click an element. Here is an example for c#

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.ng2-smart-page-link.page-link.page-link-next"));
```

Another recommendation, you may try to use **Katalon Recorder**

See Details and Download at

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid

It is used for creating script based on your action while recording. So that you can search solution for selecting by **ID**, **Class**, or **CSSSelector**.